# How to create and use a resource file not related to aspx page or global resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, resources

I am working on a web app using asp.net web forms and I have in the project's structure a directory that contains a lot of classes that requires a localized strings, so basically I want to make a couple of resources files that will be just for those classes in this very specific subdirectory.

I searched on how to do this but what I have found is related to the global resources and the local resources files and the later one is intended to be used with aspx pages which in my case is not applicable.

Also, I tried `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject` but it is just retrieving on the aspx page level!

Is there a way to use resources files related to some classes under a subdirectory in asp.net we forms?

Answer (score 0):

use `ResXResourceSet`

```
// Get resources from .resx file.
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(@"path to resx file"))
{
     // Retrieve the string resource for the title.
     this.Text = resxSet.GetString("Title");
     // Retrieve the image.
     Icon image = (Icon) resxSet.GetObject("Information", true);
}
```

example taken from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This class is located under System.Windows.Forms in System.Resources Namespace and my Application is a web app which doesn't have the assembly required and I don't think this is the best way to do it!

Comment: True you will have to include another library - by your question I think you are looking for read in any resx file from a path - which from my knowledge this is the only way.  If you don't like include another library (and I do agree it is not elegant, but it is easiest), then the only option left is add it to visual studio project, which it will be compile into a resource file then you can use `ResourceManager` to access it. Or the other option is read it as xml. so in a nutshell, without using `ResXResourceSet ` you have to do quite some work.